# Stuck at network configuration part

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, network-bonding

The dialogue option never changes to "done" or "continue" during network configuration. Instead it only says "continue without network".
I don't have ethernet port on my laptop. I am trying with wifi.

Comment: could you add an image?

Answer (score 1):

> it only says "continue without network".

Then that's your only option. I recommend that you select it and continue.

The fact that no wireless network was detected and automatically configured suggests that there is probably no working driver for your wireless device. After installation, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Next, start a new question and include the result. We'll be glad to help you.